# AT (@) Sign beginning and end

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a system that has a number of canned reports and we are looking to further customize those reports.  Looking at the XML, I see the following SELECT statement.

```
SELECT     @GetProperty("VATFlag","0",false)@ AS CONDITION
FROM        LOCATION_ORGANIZATION
WHERE     organizationID @organizationid@
```

Now, I see that @organizationid  is a variable required in the report, and I can pass something to it. However, I don't know what the dual @ in @organization@ is, also, why the strings within SELECT and AS CONDITION are and what it would return.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: I'd guess those `@` signs delimit placeholders for whatever reporting engine is consuming your XML. Notice that there is no `=` in `organizationID @organizationid@` - `@organizationid@` must contain both a comparison operator (such as `=`, `IN`, or `LIKE`) and the value(s) to compare. The same is probably true for the values between`@` signs in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: That actually makes sense, I did notice there was no operator and I couldn't put the two together that this is not a SQL variable but an artifact for the reporting engine. Thanks!